# glibc configure doesn't recognize Linux header files

Tags: linux, glibc

I've downloaded Linux kernel source from kernel.org to cross-compile glibc onto aarch64 Linux (emulated by QEMU). However, when I run:

```
[teo.samarzija@teos-acer-laptop glibc-2.31-build]$ ../glibc-2.31/configure --with-headers=/home/teo.samarzija/linux-5.7.6/include --with-binutils=/home/teo.samarzija/arm-gcc/bin --prefix=/home/teo.samarzija/arm-gcc --build=x86_64-pc-linux --host=aarch64-none-linux-gnu CC=aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc
```

I get this error:

```
checking installed Linux kernel header files... missing or too old!
configure: error: GNU libc requires kernel header files from
Linux 3.2.0 or later to be installed before configuring.
The kernel header files are found usually in /usr/include/asm and
/usr/include/linux; make sure these directories use files from
Linux 3.2.0 or later.  This check uses <linux/version.h>, so
make sure that file was built correctly when installing the kernel header
files.  To use kernel headers not from /usr/include/linux, use the
configure option --with-headers.
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: try instaling the linux header package i think on arch it is sudo apt install kernel-headers then you should be able to use your system headers to compile

Comment: @justaguy:
`[teo.samarzija@teos-acer-laptop ~]$ sudo yum install kernel-headers`

`Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo`

`Package kernel-headers-3.10.0-1127.13.1.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version`

`Nothing to do`

Comment: to use the system Headers you have to delete the --with-headers form your Argument list.

Comment: @justaguy Tried that, no good.

Comment: So does the file `/usr/include/linux/version.h` exists? Or `/home/teo.samarzija/linux-5.7.6/include/linux/version.h`? You have to install kernel sources cross-compiled for aarch64-none-linux-gnu.

Comment: @KamilCuk No, those files don't exist. There is a file `/home/teo.samarzija/linux-5.7.6/include/linux/iversion.h`, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `--with-headers=/home/teo.samarzija/linux-5.7.6/include`

This looks like a checked-out kernel tree. You need to install the kernel tree first and specify that location, using a command like this:

```
make -C /home/teo.samarzija/linux-5.7.6 ARCH=arm64 \
  INSTALL_HDR_PATH=/home/teo.samarzija/linux-5.7.6-installed/usr \
  headers_install
```

(You still have to set `CC` et al. appropriate to pick up the cross-compiler.)

And the use `--with-headers=/home/teo.samarzija/linux-5.7.6-installed/usr/include`.

Comment: "aarc64" doesn't work. Can I use "arm64", the kernel builds successfully then?

Comment: Sorry, yes, the kernel calls the architecture `arm64`. Note that make invocation will not build the kernel, only install the header files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your host configure binary by installing auto tools package or similar for your Linux. Try with the CFLAGS="-I /home/teo.samarzija/linux-5.7.6/include"